# How can I know if a column in a table is really changed

Tags: sql

How can I know if a column in a table is really changed?
for example,
I have the table product with the following rows:

```
id  | prod_name  | prod_code  | is_used
_________________________________________
1   | prod1      | code1      | 1
2   | prod2      | code2      | 0
3   | prod3      | code3      | 0
4   | prod4      | code4      | 0
5   | prod5      | code5      | 0
6   | prod6      | code6      | 0
```

I execute the following query

```
update product set is_used = 1 where prod_name like 'prod%'
```

In this simple example, all the rows will have is_used = 1
How can I know that for the first row is_used isn't changed ?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Why do you want that? Your statement is quite clear, you want to update all the products rows in products table, where their name starts with 'prod'. I can't get you.

Comment: do you want to know how may rows affected after you query? not making a lot of sense.

Comment: You could have an extra field `Updated` and use `update product set is_used = 1, Updated = 1 where prod_name like 'prod%'`

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You don't see that record 1 hasn't changed, alright, but you don't see that records 2 to 6 did change either. So what is it you really want?

Comment: this is just an example, just I wanna know if there is a way to know if a column is really changed , for the moment I think that triggers are the best solution

Comment: Yes, in triggers you can detect row changes - and log them for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a trigger that compares the previous value of the field to the updated value of the field, and then performs whatever action you want if the field is "really" changed.

Answer (score 1):

You have maintain an updated Datetime column and update it with the current Datetime when you update that row/column or have an audit table to capture the history.